# Can I export a Spline gltf with textures and colors, to a three js scene?

Tags: three.js, 3d, spline

I managed to import a spline object (.gltf) into my three js scene.
However, it does not import any textures, just the geometry.
Is there a way to do this?

```
gltfLoader.load(
    '/models/room-spline.gltf',
    (gltf) =>
    {
        gltf.scene.scale.set(0.025, 0.025, 0.025)
        gltf.scene.position.set(0,2,0)
        gltf.scene.rotation.set(0,3.5,0)
        scene.add(gltf.scene)
      
    }
)
```

This works for the geometry, but it does not import the textures...

Comment: This isn't really a coding issue, but a Spline feature issue. Have you [read through their docs](https://docs.spline.design/) to see how to export textures? If not, you might have better luck by following [their community link](https://discord.com/invite/M9hNDMqvnw), since they focus specifically on Spline.

Answer (score 1):

As of now, free tier only offer Grey Scale, and when you import, the model will appear with no texture.
You need to upgrade to Super to export with Color and Texture.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).